# On the vector $(\epsilon,\epsilon^2,\cdots,\epsilon^n)$ as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

For $\epsilon>0$, define $v(\epsilon)=(\epsilon,\epsilon^2,\cdots,\epsilon^n)\in\Bbb R^n$. Let $V$ be a proper subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Is it true that $v(\epsilon)\notin V$ for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$?

---

For $n=2$ it is easy to see the answer is yes, but I am not sure about the general case. I feel like the answer should be well-known but I can't find a reference for this anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every proper subspace $V\;$of$\;\mathbb{R}^n$ is contained in a hyperplane $H$ through the origin, with equation of the form
$$a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n = 0$$
where $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a_1,...,a_n$ are not all zero.

But the equation
$$a_1\epsilon + \cdots + a_n\epsilon^n=0$$
has only finitely many solutions, since the LHS is a nonzero univariate polynomial in the variable $\epsilon$, with real coefficients.

Thus, with finitely many exceptions, $v(\epsilon) \notin H$.

Your claim follows.